# Non-standard Core Data setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm taking an iOS development course and the current project I'm working on (with the training wheels off) directs me to use Core Data to save information.

I've used Core Data on past projects, but it was a simple Master-Detail VC setup where there it was instantiated in the root view controller using "canned code", etc.

The stack on my current project is contained in the `AppDelegate` implementation file. What should my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` look like in the `AppDelegate` implementation if my Core Data TVC isn't in the normal place it is in the "canned code"?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // TODO: get this set up
    SavedPOITableViewController *tableViewController = [[SavedPOITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableViewController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't allow your mind to become confined by any requirement to placing your core data stack into your app delegate implementation file.

I have a robust and multi-layered Core Data object graph, the stack of which is built in a separate class I call `EstablishCoreData` and I have seen others that name this similarly `CoreDataStack`, etc.

In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I have a single line...

```
[self configureCoreData];
```

that relates to this app delegate custom method...

```
- (void)configureCoreData {
    //  Establish connection to EstablishCoreData
    if (!connectCoreData)
        connectCoreData = [[EstablishCoreData alloc] init];

    //  Initiate Core Data stack and set the managedObjectContexts PRIVATE & MAIN
    if (!self.appDelegatePrivate || !self.appDelegateMain) {
        [connectCoreData configureCoreDataStack];
        [self setAppDelegatePrivate:connectCoreData.mocPrivate];
        [self setAppDelegateMain:connectCoreData.mocMain];
        NSLog(@"\n%@ - %@ -> Confirm CORE DATA configured with\nNEW managedObjectContext PRIVATE: %@  and\nNEW managedObjectContext MAIN: %@_\n\n", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.appDelegatePrivate, self.appDelegateMain);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n%@ - %@ -> Confirm CORE DATA already configured with\nEXISTING managedObjectContext PRIVATE: %@  and\nEXISTING managedObjectContext MAIN: %@_\n\n", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.appDelegatePrivate, self.appDelegateMain);
    }
}
```

obviously there is more running in the background.

In my app delegate's private declaration I include...

```
@interface AppDelegate () {
    EstablishCoreData *connectCoreData;
}
```

and the most important of these lines relates to the custom method in my class `EstablishCoreData` that kicks everything into place, being...

```
[connectCoreData configureCoreDataStack];
```

This custom method in my custom class identifies and/or instantiates my:

- `NSURL *modelURL;`
- `NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;`
- `NSURL *storeURL;`
- `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;`
- `NSPersistentStore *persistentStore;`

and of course sets the:

- main `NSMananagedObjectContext`, and
- private `NSMananagedObjectContext`.

Within my primary and initial view controller - a table view controller - I include the following public variables...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextPrivate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextMain;
```

and the following implementation code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (DD_AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [self setManagedObjectContextPrivate:appDelegate.appDelegatePrivate];
    [self setManagedObjectContextMain:appDelegate.appDelegateMain];

    ...<< etc other code as required >>...

}
```

Everything flows beautifully downstream from there using view controller hierarchy.

Read Marcus C Zarra's awesome book, from The Pragmatic Bookshelf, "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013).

Also worth mention is, from Apress publishers, "Pro iOS Persistence Using Core Data", by Michael Privat and Robert Warner.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference of the data stack initialized in the `AppDelegate`. And pass the reference of `NSManagedObjectContext` to your Root ViewController in order for later use. In addition, save your context when the app is off.

Try this:

```
lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let vc = self.window!.rootViewController as YourViewController
//YourViewController should have the property `context` in order for you to use the stack context later
vc.managedContext = coreDataStack.context
}
```

and:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
coreDataStack.saveContext()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
coreDataStack.saveContext()
}
```

`CoreDataStack` :

```
class CoreDataStack {
  let context:NSManagedObjectContext
  let psc:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
  let model:NSManagedObjectModel
  let store:NSPersistentStore?

  init() {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let modelURL =
    bundle.URLForResource("Dog Walk", withExtension:"momd")
    model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!

    psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:model)

    context = NSManagedObjectContext()
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

    let documentsURL = applicationDocumentsDirectory()
    let storeURL =
    documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Name")

    let options =
    [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true]

    var error: NSError? = nil
    store = psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: options, error:&error)

    if store == nil {
      println("Error adding persistent store: \(error)")
      abort()
    }

  }

  func saveContext() {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if context.hasChanges && !context.save(&error) {
      println("Could not save: \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
  }

  func applicationDocumentsDirectory() -> NSURL {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
      inDomains: .UserDomainMask) as [NSURL]

    return urls[0]
  }

  }
```

Comment: i'm sorry my code is in Swift, it's from the book 'CoreData by Tutorial'

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and thorough response! This app is Objective-C, but I can see this being useful in future projects.